# Calling one file in which there are multiple file names and has to be run in parallel

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

[image]Imagine, a sample.txt file contains multiple file names (a.sh,b.sh,c.sh...). I have another file test.sh, through which I want to run all the files in parallel present in sample.txt and get exit status of each file.
Can you please help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to run `test.sh a.sh`, then `test.sh b.sh`?

Comment: No. Using test.sh I want to run scripts present in sample.txt... @mark setchell

Comment: So what are the first 2 commands that will run?

Comment: I'm a beginner, so I don't know much about it. It will be helpful if you provide the solution

Comment: Ok, what is in `test.sh` then?

Comment: Nothing...I want to write command in test.sh to run all the scripts in parallel present in sample.txt

Comment: Ok, we are nearly there - what do you want to do with the exit statuses when you know them? Do you want to stop if one fails maybe?

Comment: No it shouldn't stop till everything is completed. I want to get the exit status because to know which scripts have been failed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think you want this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
export PATH=.:$PATH

parallel -a sample.txt '{} ; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "PASS:" {}; else echo "FAIL:" {};fi'
```

Comment: Thanks mark... But does this shows which script has been failed exactly?

Comment: I have made it more explicit.

Comment: Very similar to: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Function-tester

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell , i have included screenshot. Can you let me know what is the problem?

Comment: Hi @OleTange, it would be grateful if you can provide solution for the above problem.

Comment: Your PATH appears not to contain the current directory, called `.`. Try adding a line like this before `parallel`, `export PATH=.:$PATH`. Also, you should add a shebang as the first line, e.g. `#!/usr/bin/bash`. Also, make sure you have made all your scripts executable with `chmod +x *sh`.

Comment: Please copy Mark's command. Don't type it by hand. You are missing at least one important space (after 0).

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell , the above command is working.Now I want to pass parameters to the scripts (a.sh, b.sh...) and store the exit status of the scripts in a log file. Can you tell me how can i do it?

Comment: Put the parameters after the script name, `a.sh param1 param2`. If you want to direct the output to a log, use `test.sh > log.txt`

Answer (score 0):

First test that you can run the commands in serial:

```
bash sample.txt
```

If this fails, fix that first; GNU Parallel will not magically make something work that did not work before.

Then define the testing function:

```
  tester() {
    if (eval "$@") >&/dev/null; then
      perl -e 'printf "\033[30;102m[ OK ]\033[0m @ARGV\n"' "$@"
    else
      perl -e 'printf "\033[30;101m[FAIL]\033[0m @ARGV\n"' "$@"
    fi
  }
  export -f tester
```

Then call the testing function:

```
  parallel tester :::: sample.txt
```

If you are not using `bash` (and `export -f` fails above) then try (use version 20161022 or later):

```
  env_parallel tester :::: sample.txt
```

If your fix above was to prepend each line with `bash` you can make GNU Parallel do that (in which case you do not need to fix `sample.txt`):

```
  parallel tester bash :::: sample.txt
```

To run more jobs in parallel use `-j0`. To get the actual exit code use `--joblog mylog.txt` and look in `mylog.txt`.

Comment: Hi, its displaying export: Illegal option -f.

Comment: Then you are not using bash. Use env_parallel as describe above.

Comment: Ahh, I see you do: `sh test.sh`. Try instead: `bash test.sh`.

Comment: @SumanNagaraj GNU Parallel buffers output. I think you will benefit greatly from spending an hour on walking through `man parallel_tutorial`. It will give you a much better understanding of what to expect.